# How we convert group_concat function of sql in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, sequelize.js, aggregation-framework

**group_concat** of sql in mongoose?

```
[Sequelize.fn('group_concat', Sequelize.col('id')), 'products']
```

Query written in sql using sequelize. I am expecting to convert it in to mongoose.

Comment: I'd remove `Sequelize` part from the question and show SQL only, like: `group_concat(id) as products`. That way mongoose experts can help better I guess

Answer (score 0):

Use **aggregation frameworks** of mongodb

Conversion of above code is

- **id** is equal to **_id** in mongodb

Insert below line of code in aggregation object.

```js
{$group:{id:"_id",products:{Spush:"$_id"}}
```